# BUS Error C++ reading file

Tags: c++, input, bus

Im trying to do a very simple thing, read numbers from a file using ifstream in C++.
My input file called POSCAR

```
supercell                              
   1.00000000000000
     7.3287291297858630    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    7.3287291297858630    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    7.3287291297858630
   Au   Cu
     1    31
```

My code to read these lines goes as follows:

```
ifstream poscar("POSCAR");
  getline(poscar,skip); //Skipping comment first line
    cout<<skip<<endl;
  // Reading in the cubic cell coordinates
    int factor;
    poscar>>factor;
    cout<<factor<<endl;     
 int nelm[10]; // number of elements in the alloy
    float ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz,cx,cy,cz;
    poscar>>unit_cell[0][0]>>unit_cell[0][1]>>unit_cell[0][2];
    poscar>>unit_cell[1][0]>>unit_cell[1][1]>>unit_cell[1][2];
    poscar>>unit_cell[2][0]>>unit_cell[2][1]>>unit_cell[2][2];
```

I get this error when I output what it has read:

```
supercell                              
1inf7.328730
0inf7.32873
 7.3287291297858630
-142571760010922
Bus error
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong. I thought the >> takes care of the tab spaces.

Comment: `1.00000000000000`. Integers, in text form, can't have decimal points in them.

Answer (score 2):

`factor` is declared as an `int`; it should be a `float` or `double`. And similarly for `unit_cell`, which isn't declared in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JosephQuinsey. Here's the code I wrote as a test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string skip;
    ifstream poscar("/tmp/POSCAR.txt");
    getline(poscar, skip);
    cout << skip << endl;

    while (poscar.good())
    {
        double factor;
        poscar >> factor;
        cout << factor << endl;
    }

    poscar.close();
    return 0;
}
```